# When implements DiscoveryListener java app stopped

Tags: java-me, bluetooth, alcatel-ot

i try create application for Alcatel OT 808. But when I load application with class that implements DiscoveryListener, and then start this application, phone says: Java app stopped.

But in emulator all right.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This model doesn't support bluetooth in user's Java applications. Problem solved by using antoher device.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hi, DiscoveryListener method does not return or the return is delayed, the system may be blocked. Please read [DiscoveryListener API](http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/DiscoveryListener.html), [Also Check Code with Discussion](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?127042-DiscoveryListener-Q#post387343)

Comment: Thanks, but I have this problem with all applications that uses bluetooth, I think that it's problem on hardware...

Comment: Try on different Mobiles, Please accept answer if you satisfied so another people check this Question and Answer...... Thanks